# Get the first child <div> class name after sortable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I like to get the class names of the first child div's(not all div class name) after a button click.

But I am struck on it.

I have tried the following.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="test_1">
        Test 1
        <div class="sub_1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="test_2">
        Test 2
        <div class="sub_2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="test_3">
        Test 3
        <div class="sub_3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="test_4">
        Test 4
        <div class="sub_4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="test_5">
        Test 5
        <div class="sub_5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="test_6">
        Test 6
        <div class="sub_6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="target">
    Click Me
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(function(){
    $( "#container" ).sortable();
    $( "#container" ).disableSelection();
});  

var arr = new Array();
    $( "div#target" ).click(function() {
        $('div', $('div#container')).each(function() {
            arr.push($(this).attr('class'));
        });
        console.log(arr);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            success: function(data) {
                window.location.href = 'test.php?data='+arr
            },
        });
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y0L03bc4/)

My Current Code is giving me all the child div class name's.

My desired Output is:

> ["test_2 ui-sortable-handle",
>
> "test_1 ui-sortable-handle",
>
> "test_4 ui-sortable-handle",
>
> "test_3 ui-sortable-handle",
>
> "test_6 ui-sortable-handle",
>
> "test_5 ui-sortable-handle"],

But I am currently getting the following output

> ["test_2 ui-sortable-handle", "sub_2", "test_1 ui-sortable-handle",
> "sub_1", "test_4 ui-sortable-handle", "sub_4", "test_3
> ui-sortable-handle", "sub_3", "test_6 ui-sortable-handle", "sub_6",
> "test_5 ui-sortable-handle", "sub_5", "test_2 ui-sortable-handle",
> "sub_2", "test_1 ui-sortable-handle", "sub_1", "test_4
> ui-sortable-handle", "sub_4", "test_3 ui-sortable-handle", "sub_3",
> "test_6 ui-sortable-handle", "sub_6", "test_5 ui-sortable-handle",
> "sub_5"]

How to get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/r539cuw2/

use * to get similar sub-string class name with "test"

```
$(function(){
            $( "#container" ).sortable();
            $( "#container" ).disableSelection();
});

var arr = new Array();
$( "div#target" ).click(function() {
    $( "div[class*='test']" ).each(function() { // use * to get simir sub-string class name with "test"
        arr.push($(this).attr('class'));
    });
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `children()` function.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y0L03bc4/1/)

```
$(function(){
            $( "#container" ).sortable();
            $( "#container" ).disableSelection();
});

var arr = new Array();     

$("div#target").click(function() {
    $('div#container').children().each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).attr('class'));
    });
    console.log(arr);
});
```

(or)

```
   $("div#target").click(function() {
    var arr = $('div#container').children().map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('class');
    }).get();
    console.log("arr", arr);
});
```